# Google Map API Autocomplete filter germany postal Code

Tags: google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I want to filter Autocomplete result for a City in Germany!

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=geometry,places"></script>

var optionsss = {
        types: ['(regions )'],
        componentRestrictions: {
            country: 'DE',
            postal_code: '24103'
        }
    };

var autocompleteInvoiceAdd = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('searchInput'));
```

Comment: What problems do you have with the code you posted?

Comment: While you define the [AutoCompleteOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#AutocompleteOptions), you don't actually pass it into the [AutoComplete constructor](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Autocomplete)

Comment: Also, it looks like the only valid (documented) property for the [ComponentRestrictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#ComponentRestrictions) is `country`.

Comment: I want to define 24103 as Postal Code, this postal Code is Valid postal Code in Germany!

Comment: Autocomplete should be find address only in this zone!!

Comment: I think you might need to make a feature request for it to work that way then.

Comment: This code worked not well.

Answer (score 0):

I would take out `types: ['(regions )'],` and check if it works. There is not **address type** of `regions`.[Here is list of address types defined by Google.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Types)

Component restriction parts seems right.